# Need some tutorial links abut TUI in Console application in C

Tags: c, windows, console-application, tui

I want to make a console based application like Norton Commander in C.
I don't have problems with writing the core.
I neet some tutorials about how to make a TUI in windows console (using windows.h).
I need it to be something like this:

[image: NC]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be the [PDCurses](http://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm) library is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have started writing a C library version of my [`Tickit`](http://metacpan.org/module/Tickit) Perl module, which provides terminal UI abilities. The eventual completion of this will provide a set of high-level widget-based code to build full-screen interactive UIs. For now, the C library has the lower level screen output and keyboard/mouse input code, but is lacking the windows and widgets of a full application.

It's very much a work-in-progress at this point so it's not quite yet available as an easy end-user library, but if you would be interested I could try to get something release-ready at this lower layer at least.